# Add Visual Studio 2012 Places shortcut in open project dialog

Tags: visual-studio-2012

How do I add a shortcut to the places bar in Visual Studio 2012? I know I can add to the Favourites but can't find anywhere how to add it to the Visual Studio part.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by changing option under

Tools -> Options -> Project and Solutions -> General tab

Like below and it will look up in that folder[image]

Hope it helps

Comment: Ah brilliant thanks for that, but is there no way to add multiple shortcuts there?

Comment: Sorry mate you can not do that I tried but there is no way to do that... Best luck